# How do I fix the prompt Open AI response?

Tags: ios, swift

I am using the OpenAI API to generate text completions for prompts, but I am encountering an issue where the API response returns an error

> No value associated with key CodingKeys(stringValue: "object",
> intValue: nil) ("object")

I have checked that the prompt I am sending is valid and I have tested with different prompts, but the issue persists. What could be causing this problem and how can I fix it? Any help or insights would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

```
class NetworkManager{
    static let shared = NetworkManager()
    
    @frozen enum Constants{
        static let key = ""
    }
    
    
    private var client: OpenAISwift?
    
    private init() {}
    
    func setUp(){
        self.client = OpenAISwift(authToken: Constants.key)
    }
    func getResponse(input: String, completion: @escaping (Result<String, Error>) -> Void) {
        let prompt = """
            translate from English to Nigerian Pidgin:

            \(input)

            Output:
            """

        
        client?.sendCompletion(with: prompt, model: .gpt3(.davinci), maxTokens: 60) { result in
            switch result {
            case .success(let response):
                let output = response.choices.first?.text ?? ""
                print(response)
                completion(.success(output))
            case .failure(let error):
                completion(.failure(error))
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        }
    }
    
  networkManager.getResponse(input: inputText) { result in
               switch result {
               case .success(let outputText):
                   DispatchQueue.main.async {
                       self.secondTextField.text = outputText
                   }
               case .failure(let error):
                   print("Error translating text: \(error)")
               }
           }
```

Comment: It looks like your json decoding fails.

Comment: I met the same issue.